# Time derivative of a time derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Something I've seen in multiple multivariable calculus proofs is that if

y' = f(y)

then

df/dt = f<sub>t</sub> + f*f<sub>y</sub>

where f<sub>t</sub> and f<sub>y</sub> are the partial derivatives of f with respect to t and y, respectively.

Why is this?  It's something I've never understood very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide a reference which has the expression you have written?

If $f = f(y(t))$ then

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial t},$$

which follows from the chain rule.  If $f = f(t, y(t))$ then

$$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.$$

Again, this fact follows from the chain rule for multivariable functions.

Comment: Oh wow I'm a dolt for not realizing I needed to write it as f(y(t)).  It is, indeed, y(t).  I'm doing Taylor expansions for a third order Runge-Kutta scheme and was getting stumped on the multiple derivatives.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your expansions... I know first hand that they become quite tedious quite quickly!! :D